# Regular expression: does Kleene star have a distributive property?

Tags: regex, kleene-star

Would there be a difference between `(aa)*` and `(a*a*)`?

Is there a distributive property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kleene star does not distribute. `(ab)*` is very different from `(a*b*)`.

In your specific example, `(aa)*` would match groups of two `a`s (thus, it only matches even numbers of `a`s), while `(a*a*)` is equivalent to `(a*)` and matches any sequence of `a`s. (In that case, `L((aa)*)` is a proper subset of `L((a*a*))`, but this is not necessarily true for a general regex).

Answer (score 1):

The `(aa)*` group does not match the whole `aaa` so yes, there's a difference, it only return you a group of 2 `a`.

But `(a*a*)` is just the same as `(a*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference. (aa)* would be groups of aa, whereas (a*a*) would be a's.

Basically, the first phrasing would only be even numbers of a, whereas the second would not in this case.